# DelphiXE2 vs Delphi7. dll behaviour depends on calling process

Tags: delphi, dll, delphi-xe2

I have both Delphi7 and DelphiXE2 (both 32-bit) installed on my machine. And I need to use a function openSocket() from dll 'libnodave.dll'.

The problem is that in Delphi7 and in .exe-file compiled by D7 this function executes in a moment and returns some integer value, but in DelphiXE2 it stops for 3 seconds (timeout i guess) and returns zero.
I've tried to write a kind of 'proxy-dll' in D7 witch calls same function from original dll internally but it doesn't work. 
Now I'm interested what other information of program's execution is passed to dll besides local function parameters. How it could happened that library makes difference in it's behavior depending on who calls the function. And is there a way to set up DelphiXE compiler to act as D7 compiler?
Another little question: How can I look through all global parameters defined in program (like {$DEFINE WIN32}) while debugging.

Thank's for any ideas.

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference between calling dll functions in Delphi 7 and XE2.
But function declared as

```
function openSocket(port:longint;name:pchar):longint; stdcall;
    external LibName {$ifdef WIN32} name 'openSocket'{$ENDIF};
```

where PChar was `AnsiChar` in Delphi 7 but Unicode (`WideChar`) in XE2. I can guess it is still AnsiChar in this dll and you can:

1. openSocket(yourPort, PAnsiChar(UTF8Encode(name))) where name is of `string` type (you will see warnings)
2. rename all occurrences of `pchar` to `PAnsiChar` in nodave.pas and use `AnsiString` and `PAnsiString` instead of `string` and `pchar`.

Answer (score 1):

> The problem is that in Delphi7 and in .exe-file compiled by D7 this
>   function executes in a moment and returns some integer value, but in
>   DelphiXE2 it stops for 3 seconds (timeout i guess) and returns zero.

What does the declaration of the `openSocket()` function look like?  Do the calling conventions match in both versions?  Does the function have any `String` parameters?  Remember that `String` is Ansi in D7 and Unicode in DXE2.  Make sure the function is declared with the same calling convention and all of the parameters are declared with the correct data types in both versions.

> I'm interested what other information of program's execution is passed
>   to dll besides local function parameters.

No information is passed to the function other than its parameter values.

> is there a way to set up DelphiXE compiler to act as D7 compiler?

No, you cannot make the XE2 compiler act like the D7 compiler.

> How can I look through all global parameters defined in program (like
>   {$DEFINE WIN32}) while debugging.

There is no way to view the active compiler DEFINEs at debug-time.  At edit-time, however, there is a keyboard shortcut, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>, that inserts the currently active DEFINEs into your source code.

Comment: That would be `Ctrl+O+O`, but it doesn't include things like `WIN32` or `POSIX`. It includes things like warnings, range checking and overflow, min enum size, and that sort of thing (IOW, the defines that you can change, not the built in constant ones).